# Image from json file is not displayed on the website

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, database

I want to fetch images from json to javascript function but instead of displaying the image it instead just displays the name of image file. Below is the javascript function

```
            import React from "react";
        import IosAppName from './appStoreData.json';
        import './Ios_search.css';
        import {useState} from 'react';

        function Ios_search(){
            const[searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')
            return(
                <div className='ios'>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Search' onChange={event => {setSearchTerm(event.target.value)}}></input>
                    {IosAppName.filter(
                        app_name =>{
                            if(searchTerm == '') return ''
                            else if(app_name.appStore.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) return  app_name
                        }
                        
                    )

                    .map((all_app_names) => {return <p>{all_app_names.appStore} {all_app_names.image}</p>})}
                </div>
            );
        }

        export default Ios_search;
```

And this is the dummy data

```
[
    
    {"appStore":"Cardguard",
    "image": "AS.jpg"},
    {"appStore":"Temp"},
    {"appStore":"Tempsoft"},
    {"appStore":"Stim"},
    {"appStore":"Tin"},
    {"appStore":"Aerified"},
    {"appStore":"Ventosanzap"},
    ]
```

this is what it looks like when searched-
[Searchbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt6tV.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display an image in a website you should use the `<img>` tag. Right now `{all_app_names.image}` lives inside a `<p>` tag. That's why it simply shows the files name. You can re-write this to be

```
 .map((all_app_names) => {return <p>{all_app_names.appStore} <img src={all_app_names.image}/> </p>})}
```

However, something to note, the src attribute in the image tag, requires the proper direct path value or direct link.

If the direct path value is incorrect, it will display an empty image placeholder.

Depending where the image you are fetching is stored, you may have to tweak your database attained value, a little bit.
You can read more about img tags here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: is there a way I can fetch my image from my src/image folder because when I give the path to my image tag in json file, it only displays a default question mark image, but when I provided a web image address to the json file and it worked, but its not working for my local image

Comment: Hey there is :). But you must use the direct path to it relative to the index.html file. If in your root, you have index.html and your src folder, the path would be ./src/images/Image.jpg. this is what I meant by tweaking your JSON given value. But again the exact path depends on your file directory structure. As an example, to add on that path to the JSON value, you can simply write <img src={"./src/images/" + all_app_names.image}/>

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too but was able to solve it by just moving my images to the public folder and fetching them from there.
This is not only easier, it also eliminates complex file path hierarchy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).